# Android:Media Player difference between PrepareAsync() and Prepare()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wanted to implement basic media player functionality and was confused between PrepareAsync()
and Prepare() method calls. Which one should be used if the audio file is in the raw folder .

Comment: Both do the same thing at the end, but Prepare() will not return until preparation is done, while PrepareAsync will return immediately and do the preparation in the background.

Comment: It means Suppose I have audio clip of say for example 10 min . . PrepareAsync will return audio for first few seconds immediately and prepare might take a bit longer to get the file read but once its done it will return the object for the whole file ?

Comment: You can't start playing before the preparation is done or you will have an exception. With PrepareAsync() you will have to start the playback yourself in the "onPrepared" method of the onPreparedListener.

Answer (score 17):

The difference between those methods is basically in what thread they're executed.

`Prepare` runs in the thread you call it (most frequently UI thread) and thus if it takes long time (buffering video from the Internet and such) it will block your UI thread and a user might get ANR.

`PrepareAsync` runs in a background thread and thus UI thread is not blocked as it returns almost immediately. But the player is not prepared so you want to set `onPreparedListener` in order to know when the `MediaPlayer` is ready to be used.

Comment: but if the use case is basic which in my case is (i.e read from raw folder resource ) I can go for Prepare() method. It would work faster in this case ?

Comment: it'll probably work a little faster (though I doubt if you notice it).
you may try yourself and see if it's blocking your UI, if not you can go for `prepare` method, but generally it'd be better to use `prepareAsync` as it won't generate problems in future.

Answer (score 13):

prepare() method is generally used when we want to play our media file synchronously. 
prepareAsync() is generally used when we want to play asynchronously.

for eg:

```
mediaplayer.prepare()
```

It is used to play the file from local media resources.

mediaplayer.prepareAsync() is generally used for playing the live data over stream. It allows to play without blocking the main thread. 
If we use `prepare()` for live data streaming it eventually crashes because the data is received in streams.
Basically what `prepare()` does it first load all the data and then it play. Thus it allows to play the media file synchronously.
And `prepareAsync()` play the data whatever it has in its buffer.

Here is the final Quotes

> here are two ways (synchronous vs. asynchronous) that the Prepared
>   state can be reached: either a call to prepare() (synchronous) which
>   transfers the object to the Prepared state once the method call
>   returns, or a call to prepareAsync() (asynchronous) which first
>   transfers the object to the Preparing state after the call returns
>   (which occurs almost right way) while the internal player engine
>   continues working on the rest of preparation work until the
>   preparation work completes. When the preparation completes or when
>   prepare() call returns, the internal player engine then calls a user
>   supplied callback method, onPrepared() of the OnPreparedListener
>   interface, if an OnPreparedListener is registered beforehand via
>   setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener).

**The main difference is that when we use files then we call prepare() and when we use streams then we call prepareAsync().**

In your case it must be prepare() method

Check [prepareAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29) and [prepare()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare%28%29) refer the docs its clearly stated