# Calling the media streaming in a different thread or not for prepareAsync()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I am streaming audio from my server. I went through the documentation of prepareAsync() [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446555/6366458) answer from stackoverflow says that it is done on a different thread than the calling UI thread.

So my question is do I need to call the task of audio streaming on a new thread as a good practice or should we continue on the same thread since prepareAsync() is done on a new thread itself.

For reference purpose I am adding my code where I have not created a new thread for calling MediaPlayer class :

`Calling Class`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String url = "http://arqamahmad.com/music_app/bensound-cute.mp3";
                    if(Player.player == null){
                        new Player();
                    }
                    Player.player.playStream(url);
                }
            });
```

`Player Class`

```
public class Player {

  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    public static Player player;
    String url = "";

    public Player(){
        this.player = this;
    }

    public void playStream (String url){
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            try{
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();// Starting only when it is prepared
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();//Doing in the background thread
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and call prepareAsync() in the same thread. When the media player is done preparing (often buffering), it notifies the app onPreparedListener() through a different thread (native thread).