# Can not connect button click action Intent in Main activity to a Pending Intent in Service class to get action in notification using .getAction()

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to connect following **MainActivity.java**'s buttonclick intents to a pendingIntent in my **RathuMakara.java** *Service class*. I tried to use CONSTANTS, but I was not successful. I want to add buttons to notification to control the music. So that I know, I should use pending intents, that's why I am trying to connect button click action in MainActivity.java to a pendingIntent in my RathuMakara.java Service class.

This is **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Button buttonStart;
    private Button buttonStop;
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSop);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    }








    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v == buttonStart){
            startService(new Intent(this, RathuMakara.class));

            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lets's Go... Collecting the Awesomeness",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        else if (v == buttonStop){
            stopService(new Intent(this, RathuMakara.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playing Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

**This is RathuMakara.java**

```
public class RathuMakara extends Service {


    public static Object action;
    private MediaPlayer rathu;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags , int startID){

        String url ="http://206.189.34.189:8000/rathumakara.mp3";
        MediaPlayer rathu = new MediaPlayer();
        rathu.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            rathu.setDataSource(url);

            rathu.prepare();

            rathu.start();


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, notificationIntent, 0);






            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.logo);


            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Rathu Makara FM")
                    .setContentText("දැන් අහන්නේ")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setOngoing(true)
//                   .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play", )
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();


            startForeground(1, notification);












        }
        catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){

        rathu.stop();
    }

}
```

This is **Rathu.java** where I created the Notification channel

```
package com.example.yomal.rathumakarafm;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class Rathu extends Application {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Example Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help Me.Thank you

Comment: what is the error you are getting? putting code dump isn't helping

Comment: I tried this tutorial, https://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/ 
I tried to add contants as they stated. But I don't have an idea , where to add , what to change. It's the problem.

Comment: Ok what is not working?

Comment: I don't know how to add pending intent matching to my code.
Eg:
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent playPending = PendingIntent.

Then after that How to connect 
if(v == buttonStart){
            startService(new Intent(this, RathuMakara.class)); to above pending intent.
Thank you

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. I will attempt to point out some things that may be helpful: 1.) You don't "connect" buttonStart to your `PendingIntent`. `PendingIntents` are used with notifications. 2.) You add a PendingIntent to your notification with that `addAction()` call you have commented. 3.) All these intents flow to the `onStartCommand()` routine of your service. You can distinguish one `Intent` from another by associating a string (such as "play" or "stop") with it via `setAction()`. Inside `onStartCommand()`, retrieve the action via `getAction()`, as in the tutorial.

Comment: @greeble31 1) Thank  you. I understand it. 2) I understand that too. 3) Here, I don't know how to do it as it stated in that tutorial. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Let's say you had 3 buttons on your notification: play, pause, stop. You associate a `PendingIntent` with each one during the `addAction()` call. When someone taps one of those buttons on the notification item, `onStartCommand()` is called. Parameter 1 is the `Intent` that came from the `PendingIntent` that was associated with that button. So, here's the question: How do you determine which of the 3 buttons was pressed, by looking at the intent?

Comment: @greeble31 as you say, I should associate them using strings. Am I right? In that tutorial they have used CONSTANTS also. So it's very confusing how to write the code. I am very new to java and android development.

Comment: @greeble31 If you  dont mind please look in to this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840281/app-stops-working-when-mediaplayer-is-stopped-in-service-class . I am very sorry to bother you in this. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you're wrong about the constants. The "Constants" they used _are just strings_. "com.truiton.foregroundservice.action.main" is just a string. It has no other meaning or linkages. They just put their package name in there to avoid naming collisions. Does that make sense?

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, now I understand what are constants. How to connect my buttons with these mediaPlayer.play , stop and pause functions. I tired 
if (intent.getAction().equals(?) Then here what should I type if I want to start the media player? is it ,mediaplayer.play() ?

Comment: Inside `onStartCommand()`, check the value of intent.getAction(), and call one of the `rathu` member functions depending on the results of that comparison.

Comment: @greeble31 Okay Thank you, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @greeble31 I was unsuccessful in implementing. May be my java knowledge is insufficient for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the notification content

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle(textTitle)
    .setContentText(textContent)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

and add action buttons

```
    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    snoozeIntent.setAction(ACTION_SNOOZE);
    snoozeIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_snooze, getString(R.string.snooze),
                snoozePendingIntent);
```